# Intentos validos .htacccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Tengo un `htaccess` y `htpasswd`, cuando ingreso a la pagina me abre el `alert` para ingresar el usuario y la contraseña. Funciona todo OK. 
Que validación debería hacer para limitar la cantidad de veces que un usuario puede colocar la combinación de Usuario y contraseña.
Quiero que a la tercera vez que ingrese mal, le brinde un error.

Mi `.htaccess` tiene la forma

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Por favor ingresa tu codigo y clave"
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

Comment: Esto no tiene nada que ver con PHP. Y sí con Apache.

Comment: Me temo lo de controlar las veces que pueden intentar acceder, lo debes controlar mediante PHP

Answer (score 1):

Buscando sobre el tema (no verificado), lo puedes controlar con el modulo `modsecurity`

Si tu servidor no lo tiene activado por defecto, [Guía de cómo se instala y configura modsecurity](http://www.linuxito.com/seguridad/562-como-instalar-y-configurar-modsecurity-en-apache-sobre-servidores-debian)

Prueba con el siguiente código que establece 3 intentos fallidos por cada IP única, si se falla en más de 3 intentos, la IP quedará bloqueada durante 10 minutos.

```
<LocationMatch /sessions>
         # Uncomment to troubleshoot
        #SecDebugLogLevel 9
        #SecDebugLog /tmp/troubleshooting.log

        # Enforce an existing IP address block
        SecRule IP:bf_block "@eq 1" \
                "phase:2,deny,\
                msg:'IP address blocked because of suspected brute-force attack'"

        # Check that this is a POST
        SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "@streq POST" "phase:5,chain,t:none,nolog,pass"
                # AND Check for authentication failure and increment counters
                # NOTE this is for a Rails application, you probably need to customize this
            SecRule RESPONSE_STATUS "^200" \
                    "setvar:IP.bf_counter=+1"

    # Check for too many failures from a single IP address. Block for 10 minutes.
    SecRule IP:bf_counter "@ge 3" \
            "phase:5,pass,t:none, \
            setvar:IP.bf_block,\
            setvar:!IP.bf_counter,\
            expirevar:IP.bf_block=600"
```

**Personalización:**

Puedes especificar los intentos de acceso, antes que se bloque la IP.

`SecRule IP:bf_counter "@ge 3" \`

y el tiempo del bloqueo en segundos (600 segundos = 10 minutos)

`expirevar:IP.bf_block=600`

Extraído de: [Brute Force Authentication Protection with ModSecurity (inglés)](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/563-Brute-Force-Authentication-Protection-with-ModSecurity)

Answer (score 0):

No se puede ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947238/limit-retries-for-secured-directory-with-htaccess-file)). Y normalmente no vale la pena. Por lo general, el mismo navegador se encarga de limitar la cantidad de reintentos.